# Nginx configuration to serve any url as root url

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I am running a simple static website under nginx with the following configuration

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;

    location /mycalendar {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

The catch:

URLs are coming in to this service as /mycalendar. However nginx still expects to find files in a "mycalendar" subdir of /usr/share/nginx/html but I would like to server them from the "root".

Is there a way to serve a /mycalendar subpath but tell nginx to take files from root instead of a subdirectory named after the subpath?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What helped in this case was to use "alias" instead of "root" inside the "location ~ /mycalendar" block.